# How test all routs to ensure they return at least a none-500 response?

Tags: laravel, testing, routes, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I want to be sure that all `GET` routes defined in `routes.php` file return a 200 response and all non-get routes return at least a non-500 http response. How can I do that using phpunit and Laravel testing facilities?

Answer (score 0):

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
         $this->route('GET', $value);
         $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
```

Get all routes and then loop through each route

Comment: This does not works. you need to get url from routes. e.g. user/1 instead of `/user/{user}/`